# Java: a Float based - Parameter doesn't recognize a float number

Tags: java, floating-point, double

My Question is i do have a function which takes in float numbers **example** 1.0, 2.0 etc etc. Now upon calling the function and passing an Argument like 2.0 -> it gives out the following Error: `The method notenAdd(float) in the type Student is not applicable for the arguments (double)`

**the Function:**

```
public void notenAdd(float k) {
    if (k>=1.0 & k<=5.0) {
        noten.add(k);
    }
}
```

**the Call:**

```
example.notenAdd(2.0);
```

What is the Issue ?

Comment: 2.0 is a double value, use 2.0f

Comment: or `(float) 2.0` or `2f` or just `2`.

Comment: In addition to the strategy of making the argument a float, not a double, is there a good reason to be using float at all? Situations in which it is better than double are rare.

Answer (score 2):

Just do this :

`example.notenAdd(2.0f);`

As simply sending value 2.0 is considered double type by default for floating point numbers.